# php script displays as text django

Tags: php, django

I have PHP script in my Django project, it should take items from postgresql base and add to drop menu, but when I use it, it only shows as text

```
div class="hot-dept-select">

        <span class="hot-dept-select__link"><u>Из <span data-departure="accusative">Москвы</span></u></span>

        <div class="hot-dept-select__touch">
            <script id="hot-dept-select-touch" type="text/html">
                <select class="hot-dept-select__select">
                    <% for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { %>
                        <option <% if (items[i].value == Global.getDepartureCity()) { %>selected="selected"<% } %>
                        value="<%= items[i].value %>"
                        data-value="<%= items[i].value %>"
                        ><%= items[i].nominative %></option>
                    <% } %>
                </select>
            </script>
        </div>

        <div class="hot-dept-select__dropdown">
            <div class="hot-dept-select__inner">
                <script id="hot-dept-select" type="text/html">
                    <% for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { %>
                        <div class="
                            hot-dept-select__item
                            <% if (i && (items[i].nominative[0] !== items[i - 1].nominative[0])) { %>
                                hot-dept-select__item_padded
                            <% } %>
                        ">
                            <a href="/hot/<%= items[i].value %>" data-value="<%= items[i].value %>"><%= items[i].nominative %></a>
                        </div>
                    <% } %>
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Django 1.5.1, python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong [php tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). They should be `<?php` and `?>`

Most likely coded by someone with `asp_tags`(<%) enabled in php.ini.

Comment: Hmmm, to be hosnest I dont knoww, in what language this script is wrote at, i've tried Django tags {} and {%} but with them drop menu is simple empty

Comment: I did´nt look at it that carefully either, its not PHP. I would guess server side javascript based on `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)`, pyhon does not have a var keyword as far as i know.